# How to get the user's country without requesting it to other web services?

Tags: php

I have to develop a service similar ( but different ) to these:

```
whatismyipaddress.com

iplocation.net
```

So, how can I get the country of the users by using their ip address and without using external web services ?

Comment: The short answer: not possible without external requests. IP ranges are assigned by the RIPE organization. There is no system in assigning addresses and assignments may change from time to time. You need to ask an external server knowing the assignments. PHP has functions doing the job for you. The server must be configured to allow outgoing requests. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.geoip.php

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Well, there are GeoIP libraries for that, you do not necessarily have to use an external service. But indeed the results using such libraries are less precise and reliable than typical services.

Comment: @arkascha That's what I've linked to the php.net documentation. However, I'm not sure if this lib provides offline information as a snapshot as well.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone My point is that you don't need external requests _if_ you use a local database.

Comment: @arkascha where can I get the database with all the associations ip -> country ? Thanks :)

Comment: MaxMind would be one option: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/

Comment: IP2Location LITE is free. http://lite.ip2location.com

Answer (score 2):

Try [Geo IP Location](http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php) . It uses offline database. But it won't be 100% accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ip to country data base. you can get it from Maxmind, IP2Location, software77, Maxmind, Geolite, ip2nation. some of free and some is paid. you can buy database from here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will always need a third party, you might need to make a dictionary for countries allocated IP ranges and check for each visit the range it belongs to.
This also won't be accurate 100%, but maybe 95%.
A website that gives ip ranges to begin with: https://www.countryipblocks.net/country_selection.php

Answer (score 0):

Below are the two free database commonly used by developers.

**IP2Location LITE**

http://lite.ip2location.com

**GeoLite2**

http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/

Both required attribution for usage.